Is there a closed form solution to the distribution of the running maximum for Gaussian processes?
Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a zero mean Gaussian process with variance $\sigma(t)=\mathbb{E}X_tX_t^\top$ and define
$$
S_T=\sup_{t\leq T}X_t\quad T\in[0,\infty)
$$
the running maximum of $X$.
Question: Does there exist a closed form solution to $S_T$ if we know $\sigma(t)$ for all $t\in[0,T]$?
At first, I tried to look at the problem by using results from stochastic calculus. Namely, if I remember correctly, as $X$ is Gaussian, then for any $T$, the stopped process $X^T$ is a martingale and if $\sigma(t)$ is predictable, then by the martingale representation theorem, we can write
$$
X_T=\int_0^T\xi\mathrm{d}W\quad\xi\in\mathcal{P}(W)_T
$$
where $\mathcal{P}(W)_T$ denotes the space of progressive processes for which $\mathbb{E}\int_0^TX_t^2\mathrm{d}\langle W\rangle_t=\mathbb{E}\int_0^TX_t^2\mathrm{d}t<\infty$. Hence, $X$ can be written as a stochastic integral with respect to a Brownian motion, and the running maximum of the Brownian motion has been well-studied. Namely, for the Brownian motion $W$, we know that
$$
P(\sup_{t\leq T}W_t>x)=P(|W_T|>x)\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \quad\forall T\in[0,\infty)
$$
and so $\sup_{t\leq T}W_t\sim|W_T|$. Now intuition tells me that perhaps
$$
S_T\sim |N(0,\int_0^T\sigma(t)\mathrm{d}t)|
$$
given that this would coincide with the case of the Brownian motion as $\int_0^T\mathrm{d}t=T$, yet coming up with a proof is harder than I anticipated.
Remark: As a small remark, I wish to use the result in order to tell whether a process is indeed a Gaussian process. Namely, under some hypothesis, the process $X$ should be Gaussian while under the alternative, the process should diverge to infinity for every $t>0$, and so if we know $\sigma(t)$ for all $t\in[0,T]$, then one could statistically test whether it is plausible that at time $T$, we observe that $S_T$ is bigger than some value $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Remark: It is worth noting that, in case $\sigma(t)$ is known (and positive), then one can consider the standardised process, for which there exists results concerning the maximum of stationary Gaussian processes, although, as far as I know, these results are only valid asymptotically. An example may be found in this paper.
